# python2.7 memory limit release

Tags: python, python-2.7

I want one Giga byte data string.

using this code

```
length = 0x20000000

payload = ''.join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(length))
```

but python excepted and print this error "MemoryError"

full error message :

```
payload = ''.join(random.choice(string.printable) for _ in range(length))
MemoryError
```

i found this excepted case in stack overflow.

using "import sys, sys.setrecursionlimit(10**6)" will fix it!

so, i adding this code.

but not solved!!

i can't "import resource". because, can't not install..

Comment: ah.. Do you have a good way for create many stirng?

Comment: How much memory does your system have?

Comment: my laptop have 8g !

Comment: Is both your OS and python install 64bit?

Comment: yes! my os version is windows 10 64bit!

Comment: I used to think it was a good idea to start with Python without understanding the underlying C code sometimes, but here is a great example of why I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best option for you is to use a `bytearray`:

```
barray = bytearray()
length = 0x20000000
for _ in range(length):
    barray.append(random.choice(string.printable))
```

This only consumed about 0.5 gigs on my machine.

Note, increasing the recursion limit won't help you here, indeed you aren't using recursion at all. You are just making something that is very large. Just the array of pointers *underlying* the `list` that gets created by `''.join` will require about `0x20000000 * 8 * 1e-9 == 4.294967296` gigabytes, and that doesn't count *the strings in the `list` themselves*, each of which requires a full python object, which is another 40 or so bytes per object, so you see, you were just running out of memory. So taking into account your individual string objects:

```
>>> 0x20000000 * (48) * 1e-9
25.769803776000003
```

So you would need over 20 gigs! Doable on some modern laptops, but 8 gigs sure isn't enough.

Comment: Any directly mutable container (so not a list) would work. Your solution is probably simplest. numpy arrays would work to. Well seen.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, a `numpy.array` would work, but a `bytearray` is essentially a mutable string in Python 2, so that's probably the most appropriate.

Comment: I am not disagreeing with you one bit. Your answer is excellent.